# Is the result in PIP or POINT?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I am new to MQL5 programming, I made below code:

```
MqlTick Latest_Price;
SymbolInfoTick(Symbol(), Latest_Price);
int gap = (Latest_Price.ask - Latest_Price.bid)/Point();
```

My question: the int that I got in the **gap** variable, is it a **PIP** or **POINT** datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That all depends on your broker and your definition of pips and points. Generally speaking in forex the correct is true.

- Pip stands for “percentage in point”.
- A pip is equivalent to 10 forex points.

For a 5 digit broker assuming you subscribe to the above definition, you `gap` variable is the amount of points and shows the current spread.